# I need help making the word UpperCase in a for loop, the word isn't written in eclipse but it is imported from a txt file

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Cascader {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner inputfile = new Scanner(new File("name.txt"));
        String name = inputfile.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Reading the name...");
        for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(name.charAt(i));
        }
        inputfile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried a lot me and my friend are doing it we tried name.toUpperCase(); in and out of the for loop, still doesn't work, It is a normal format in notepad.

Comment: Have you tried googling `How to make a word uppercase in java`?

Comment: what do you get when you do name.toUpperCase() ?

Comment: It's really hard to tell if you don't give that exact example, but I'm thinking that you aren't saving the new String. name.toUpperCase() returns a String that is entirely in upper case. You can use `String upperName = name.toUpperCase();` if you want to save the new String. If you wish to override `name`, simply use `name = name.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: I do not get a error but I still don't get the Upper case letters.

Comment: Does System.out.println print anything? If it doesn't then you're not reading the file properly if it does then you can just do System.out.println(name.toUpperCase()); outside of the for loop

Comment: Me and my friend feel stupid this is the solution - name = name.toUpperCase();

Comment: Or as RaptorDotCpp said its name = name.toUpperCase();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: you're probably not 'saving' the new String. The `toUpperCase()` method returns a new String, in which each character has been changed to upper case.

```
name.toUpperCase(); // does not do anything to the String in the variable 'name'
String newName = name.toUpperCase(); // if name was 'john', newName will be 'JOHN'
name = name.toUpperCase(); // if name was 'john', name will now be 'JOHN'
```